# BlackBerry app unable to establish Http Connection with server

Tags: http, connection, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

This is the code that I am using for an HTTP connection:

```
HttpConnection connection = null;
// InputStream inputstream = null;
connection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open("http://www.google.com");
//HTTP Request
connection.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET);
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","//text plain");
connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
add(new LabelField(""+connection.getResponseMessage()));
connection.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This BlackBerry Development Guide titled "[Code sample: Creating a connection over HTTP by using the first available transport](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11938/CS_create_first_available_HTTP_connection_857706_11.jsp)" worked!!

```
ConnectionFactory connFact = new ConnectionFactory();
ConnectionDescriptor connDesc;
connDesc = connFact.getConnection("http://www.google.com");
if (connDesc != null) {
    HttpConnection httpConn;
    httpConn = (HttpConnection)connDesc.getConnection();
    try { 
        final int iResponseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Dialog.alert("Response code: " + 
                    Integer.toString(iResponseCode));
            }
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Caught IOException: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```