# BlackBerry Dev - Downloading an image from online and displaying

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, httpconnection

So, I've been through the BlackBerry API, and the online documentation, but I'm having an issue with connecting and getting it to display. I've uploaded the image to the Apache server, and I can access it through localhost, but I can't get it to display to the screen.

I am developing in Eclipse workspace, in a windows vm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. you have to create http connection to interact with server
2. the server will send u data in bytes
3. convert this to encoded image / bitmap image and display on screen

try these:

RIM's [HttpConnection](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/javax/microedition/io/HttpConnection.html) documentation.

StackOverflow questions:

- [BlackBerry app unable to establish Http Connection with server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530927/blackberry-app-unable-to-establish-http-connection-with-server)
- [post and get data via webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743778/post-and-get-data-via-webservice/4743922#4743922)
- For converting a byte array to a bitmap: [Display static Google Map image in BlackBerry 5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775409/display-static-google-map-image-in-blackberry-5-0/4778471#4778471)